# Powershell Office 365 Calendar Permissions

Tags: powershell, office365

I am building a script to assign calendar permissions to specific people. I do this often enough to want a script.  This is what i have so far.

```
#authenticate into the office 365 account    
$LiveCred = Get-Credential

#Create new session    
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
                         -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ `
                         -Credential $LiveCred `
                         -Authentication Basic `
                         -AllowRedirection

#Import Session    
Import-PSSession $Session

#Ask for user information    
$UserCal = Read-Host -Prompt "Who's calandar are we sharing?"
$HostCal = Read-Host -Prompt "Who's needs access?"
$AccessCal = Read-Host -Prompt "What kind of access?"

#Set access for user
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ${$UserCal}:\calendar `
                            -User $HostCal `
                            -AccessRights $AccessCal
```

I believe the issue is with the `${$UserCal}:\calendar` How do i go about using a variable in this fashion?

FYI I am pretty new to Powershell and scripting. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you use for the mailbox name? Why do you use curly braces and not parentheses if needed at all?

Comment: The curly braces are what the powershell ise recommended to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question after doing much more research!

```
${$UserCal}:\calendar
```

Should be

```
$UserCal`:\calendar
```

All fixed and working perfect!